# Add attributes to django form RadioSelect and cripsy form InlineRadios

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I currently have a form with a radoi button which ill like to add arribut to the forms select new. Am suing django form and cripsy form. any help will do

```
RECORDS = ((0,'Old'),(1,'New'))

class AFile(forms.Form):
    ....
    new_record = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,choices=RECORDS,\
                 widget=forms.RadioSelect,initial='old')
   ..........
   Div(InlineRadios('new_record',),css_class='offset2')
```

Now ill like to add some attrs to the radio button on select new

```
'data-toggle'='collapse' 'data-target'='#new_record'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you pass the attributes as param='value' it renders in html output

```
Div(InlineRadios('new_record',),css_class='offset2', data_toggle='collapse', data_target='#new_record')
```